# How to concatenate rows grouped by columns in R Data frame?

Tags: r, concatenation

Sample data frame is given below . It contains column names and new column that I want to create .

```
df1<-data.frame(city=c("Delhi","Pune","Mumbai","Bangalore","Indiranagar"),ID=c(1,1,1,2,2),expected_city_col=c("Delhi Pune Mumbai","Delhi Pune Mumbai","Delhi Pune Mumbai","Bangalore Indiranagar","Bangalore Indiranagar"))
```

I want to concatenate  City rows by ID column , and create expected_city_col in my data frame .

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(newcol = paste(city, collapse= ' '))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is after grouping by 'ID', `paste` the 'city' elements together in `mutate` for creating a new column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(newcol = paste(city, collapse= ' '))
```